# JS Object Type for regex returning as NaN

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function where I'm using regex matching to check for proper date format when a `change` event happens on the value in the `input` field.

My problem is that `month`, `day`, and `year` are returning as `NaN` and I'm not sure why.  I'm parsing regex objects `[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]` respectively with `parseInt()` so I'm not sure why they are returning as `NaN`.

```
validateDate: function(event) {

        var input = $(event.target);
        var enteredDate = input.val();

        input.destroyValidationMessage();

        var pattern = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
        var result = pattern.test(enteredDate);

        if (result !== null) {
            var month = parseInt(result[1], 10);
            var day = parseInt(result[2], 10);
            var year = parseInt(result[3], 10);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.test()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns a boolean, i.e. `true` or `false` and only tells you whether the expression matches the input or not.

Then, since `if(result !== null)` is always true for `result` being either `true` or `false`, the `if` statement block is executed.

`match[x]` is the same as `true[x]` (or `false[x]`) and instead of throwing an error, it returns `undefined`. This is because JavaScript converts the primitive value to an object internally and accessing a non-existing property results in the return value `undefined`.

Furthermore, `parseInt(undefined, 10)` returns `NaN`.

---

You want to use [`.match()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var result = enteredDate.match(pattern);
```

---

A shorter way of converting a numerical string to a number is using the unary `+` operator:

```
var month = +result[1];
```

which gives you the same result here since the input string only contains digits.

Comment: I don't know whether `exec` or `test()` is correct.  Can you explain why you chose test over exec?

Comment: I used `match()` and the reason should be obvious: You cannot extract data from the input with `test()`. Have a look at the documentation. The correct method is the one that gives you the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `exec` instead of `test`:

```
var result = pattern.exec(enteredDate);
```

More about exec you can read at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: I don't know whether `exec` or `test()` is correct.  Can you explain why you chose exec over test?